# Why is a numeric value altered when it is appended to the dom with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is the snippet from a function:

```
const discountPrice = parseFloat(+(discount[1].trim())).toFixed(2).toString(); //--> 550.47
console.log(`discountPrice: ${discountPrice}`, discount[1], discountPrice); //--> discountPrice: 550.47  550.47 550.47
h += `
    <tr class="discountRow discountrowx">
        <td nowrap>
            <span class="discountDesc" discountId="${discountObj.iddiscount}">${discountType}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="discountPriceDisplay">${discountPrice.toString()}</td> 
        <input type="hidden" class="discountPrice" discountid="${discountObj.iddiscount}" name="DiscountPrice${k}" value="${discountPrice.toString()}">
    </tr>`;
console.log(`now it's:`, discountPrice);
```

This is what the string looks like after the function. It's perfect:

```
<tr class="discountRow discountrowx">
    <td nowrap>
        <span class="discountDesc" discountId="6180">Extra 30% off All Sale  (FALLFORKICKEE)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="discountPriceDisplay">550.47</td>
    <input type="hidden" class="discountPrice" discountid="6180" name="DiscountPrice0" value="550.47">
</tr>
```

Then I append it to the dom:

```
$(`#tblDiscounts`).append(h);
```

and get this:

```
<tr class="discountRow discountrowx">
    <td nowrap="">
        <span class="discountDesc" discountid="6180">Extra 30% off All Sale  (FALLFORKICKEE)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="discountPriceDisplay">550.4699999999997</td>
    <input type="hidden" class="discountPrice" discountid="6180" name="DiscountPrice0" value="550.4699999999997">
</tr>
```

The dollar value is rounding down somehow.I've tried with and without toString(). I've tried parseFloat-ing it again..nothing works.

Comment: Can you please provide snippet with repro case, as I am unable to reproduce this 

Comment: Is this `${discountPrice.toString()}` in JavaScript? You already have: `const discountPrice = parseFloat(+(discount[1].trim())).toFixed(2).toString();` so why use `.toString()` again?

Comment: That was just my latest attempt to see if adding toString made a difference.